# Can I prevent updates to the Modified column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

In a test view in SharePoint Online, I’ve added metadata columns to a small sample of older documents. However, when I enter data for the new columns, the existing Modified column is updated to today’s date. What’s the best strategy for keeping a reference to the document’s original date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per design, there is not way to prevent modified column from updating to today's date if you are using OOTB features(edit form) to update list item.  Document's original date is preserved in Created Date column which is document original date.

Though you can do it programatically using JSOM. If you are updating list items via below method it won't update modified date and modified by.

Using Native JSOM

```
const ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

const list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My list');
const item = list.getItemById(1);

item.set_item('Title', `Updated with JSOM request, ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
// item.update(); // -> creates new version, updates Editor and modified date
// item.updateOverwriteVersion(); // -> creates no new version, updates Editor and modified date
item.systemUpdate(); // -> creates no new version, Editor and modified date remains untouched

ctx.executeQuery(success, failure);
```

Ref link - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/list-items-system-update-options-sharepoint-online-andrew-koltyakov

Hope this helps..happy coding..!!!

Comment: Just going to say this is a faulty design OOTB - IMO. Meta data is data about data, not the data itself. We all need and want to know who last touched/edited a file - but when it comes to setting metadata to existing items, that modified by info should not be lost. Modified SHOULD apply to the file, not to meta data about the file. Just my opinion, thanks for the lead you offer here.